# Passing repeated item to custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass a string to a function which converts it to a JavaScript date object, called stringToDate(). The Angular date filter won't work without doing this first, as it expects a Date object. I have written the custom filter, and am using the following code in my view.

```
<div ng-repeat="blogPost in blogPosts" class="blog-item">
    <h6>{{blogPost.date | stringToDate:blogPost.date | date: 'medium' }}</h6>
</div>
```

This works, but is there a cleaner way to pass it "blogPost.date" looks cumbersome and I feel like I am not doing it the Angular way.

Comment: what does the string look like before you pass it to the `toDate` function

Comment: `"2014-11-05T15:32:17+00:00"`

Comment: When I run `<h1>{{"2014-11-05T15:32:17+00:00" | date:'medium'}}</h1>` I was able to get `Nov 5, 2014 7:32:17 AM`....was this not the case for you?

Comment: Can you post your stringToDate filter?

Comment: @prawn Now that you say it it is working for me as you say. Was getting NaN earlier. I can only assume I was making a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is already capable of formatting your date. Check date filter documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

```
<h6>{{blogPost.date | date: 'medium' }}</h6>
```

But if you want to do some custom work in your filter, you don't need to pass **blogPost.date** to your custom filter, it's implicitly passed as first parameter.

```
<div ng-repeat="blogPost in blogPosts" class="blog-item">
  <h6>{{blogPost.date | stringToDate | date: 'medium' }}</h6>
</div>
```

And your filter:

```
.filter('stringToDate', function() {
  return function (date) {
    return new Date(date);
  };
});
```

Checkout the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWLq21qkZNX5UbUdCOzp?p=preview).

Comment: That's it, I knew I was missing something essential.